# How to integrate Texmaker with MiKTeX console in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex, texmaker

I am new to LaTeX so I downloaded both Texmaker(minimum version) and MiKTeX(large version), but then I found out that when I was loading a new package in Texmaker its is asking for download but actually it was downloaded with MiKTeX.

Could someone help me how to configure Texmaker so that it can see the downloaded MiKTeX packages and directly load fonts that are within the MiKTeX package?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: did you have any particular reason to pick miktex? that is very popular on windows but rather new on linux and almost all linux tex users will be using texlive, so there will be fewer people that can help with linux miktex specific questions.

Comment: But did you try to compile after the package was downloaded? I have not used MikTex in linux (as David Carlisle said, TexLive is the standard Linux distribution) but the behavior appears to be normal. If when compiling form TexMaker you have an error, you should check MikTex rather than TexMaker. Have tried to issue `pdflatex <file.tex>` from the shell directly? There is not a lot of configuration in TexMaker: you just need to make sure that all the Latex commands are in the path.

Comment: When I try compiling in Texmaker after the package was downloaded then it compiles successfully, but my point is why to download it twice when I have it through MiKTeX console. If I can somehow show him(Texmaker) that the packages are already in MiKTeX then it will directly use it.

Comment: No, I have no particular reason to pick MiKTeX, I was using it in windows so I downloaded it for Linux. Would my problem be solved after downloading TexLive?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under ubuntu 20.04. Just sharing the solution.
I resolved my issue by manually providing the Miktex executables directory path to Texmaker.

By default, in my case, Miktex executables have been installed in /home/username/bin

In Texmaker, go : Options>Configure Texmaker > add To PATH : /home/username/bin